# How to make a Peirce Quincuncial projection with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, ngx-leaflet

I am building an Angular website with a geographical search feature. My "customers" and I would very much like to set the map with [a Peirce Quincuncial projection](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/properties/peirce-quincuncial.htm).

I have looked for a matching TIleLayer but couldn't find one, so I am beginning to think about how to build one, (if that's possible).

As I am new to SIG, could somebody(ies) share any idea for this please ?

Thank you in advance

Best regards

(Please excuse my English, I don't write very often).